# Fastest RDP client on linux

Tags: software-rec, centos, remote-desktop

I currently use KRDC on CentOS, but mouse pointer is a little slow and I'm sure that this is not caused by my internet line speed, because the windows RDP client works and everything is fine. Which RDP client is the fastest on CentOS (or any other Linux OS)?

Comment: To quote the ask question page, "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed". You need to define "best". Fastest? Most features? Most stable?

Comment: I hoped that this will obvious from my explain  before the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KRCD and I suspect all other Linux RDC clients use [`rdesktop`](http://www.rdesktop.org/) under the hood.

I'd encourage you to play with the settings of `rdesktop`, I myself have used it without any speed issues. It's very possible that your windows RDP connection uses different options, especially the `-x` parameter to `rdesktop`:

```
Changes default bandwidth performance behaviour for RDP5. By default only
theming is enabled, and all other options are disabled (corresponding
to modem (56 Kbps)). Setting experience to b[roadband] enables menu
animations and full window dragging. Setting experience to l[an] will
also enable the desktop wallpaper. Setting experience to m[odem]
disables all (including themes). Experience can also be a hexidecimal
number containing the flags.
```

Comment: Could one use any of those to connect to Windows instances of Azure / Google Cloud / AWS using RDP?

Comment: Actually, Remmina uses libfreerdp, not rdesktop.

Answer (score 6):

I cannot comment on performance/speed of various RDP clients. However I recently came across the [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/) project that describes itself as follows:

> FreeRDP is a fork of the rdesktop project that intends to rapidly start moving forward and implement features that rdesktop lacks the most.

I've not use KRDC but I have used both `rdesktop` and `xfreerdp` clients from the command-line on Ubuntu 10.10 and they are both usable. `xfreerdp` accepts the same `-x` option as @gnud mentions and that option is likely to make the biggest difference in performance.

Comment: I'm not seeing the `-x` option in the `man` page, and adding it crashes the command. My only problem is videos rendering line-by-line very visibly, even with the `/video` option. I'm using Ubuntu, and the question is 7 years old; could one or the other have removed the option?

Answer (score 1):

I've taken to using [Remmina](http://packages.ubuntu.com/remmina) [Install remmina http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/remmina) lately. I use it mostly because it manages a list of hosts and their settings quite nicely, and can set up an SSH tunnel automatically. It does VNC too.

I haven't had performance problems with RDP in general though, and haven't used KRDC, so I couldn't say it would necessarily be any different from that point of view.

I don't know if Remmina is available in CentOS's repository.

Comment: Could one use Remmina to connect to Windows instances of Azure / Google Cloud / AWS using RDP?

Answer (score 0):

OK, we found the problem.

It seems that rdp client have some trouble with Win7, so we try KRDC on others OS (CentOS, Ubuntu and XP) and it worked great...

Conclusion:
The problem is not with the RDP Client, but on the system on which we want to connect...