# CentOS 7, how to install rdesktop?

Tags: rdesktop

I would like to install **rdesktop** on CentOS 7.
If I run `sudo yum -y install rdesktop`, the system says:

```
No package rdesktop available.
```

What should I do?

[EDIT]: my os version is **CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)**

Comment: Check [additional repos](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) for `CentOS 7`, I think [nux-desktop](http://li.nux.ro/repos.html) will help you.

Comment: https://github.com/rdesktop/rdesktop lists a `rdesktop.spec` file so in theory should be buildable via `yum -y install rpm-build` and building a local RPM via `rpmbuild`, which then could be installed, or placed into a local YUM repo.

Comment: I installed rpm-build but nothing works :-(

Answer (score 8):

How about trying the included RDP client, FreeRDP?

```
$ sudo yum -y install freerdp
$ xfreerdp <server>
```

Weigh the pros and cons here: [What are the differences between rdesktop and xfreerdp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140047/what-are-the-differences-between-rdesktop-and-xfreerdp)

Comment: There so `freedrp` package available :-(

Comment: I *thought* that was on a fresh load, but I may have had EPEL loaded. Checking...

Comment: It was available for me via yum in the default configuration after loading CentOS 7.1.1503 (Core). EPEL was not installed. Perhaps you have some YUM problems?

Comment: I don't know... I'm using a **CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)** version

Comment: It is part of the base repo in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` in the default config (`mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra`). What does `yum search rdp` show for you?

Comment: This: http://s29.postimg.org/5fzb3gzwn/image.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35176/discussion-between-davidechicco-it-and-steve-bonds).

Comment: You have the 'd' misplaced in the package name: `yum -y install freerdp`

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS, the rdesktop package is in the nux-dextop repository. You need to install the repo and then rdesktop:

```
sudo rpm --import http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro 
sudo rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-1.el7.nux.noarch.rpm    
sudo yum install rdesktop
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that RHEL7 and CentOS 7 don't include `rdesktop`. Instead, they include `vinagre`, which appears to work well enough.