# Using xfreerdp to connect to Remote Desktop Gateway Server

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, xfreerdp

I am trying to use Remote Desktop connection on Linux. After some research, it seems that `xfreerdp` can do what I need. The basic usage example provided by that tool is:

```
xfreerdp /u:CONTOSO\\JohnDoe /p:Pwd123! /v:rdp.contoso.com
```

Some comments:

- `/u` corresponds to `User name:` in picture 1
- `/v` corresponds to `Server name:` in picture 2

I also need to enter a `Computer name:` (see picture 1).  How could `xfreerdp` take this into account?

[image]
[image]

I am ok with using another tool other than `xfreerdp` if it can accomplish this as well.

Comment: Related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140047/what-are-the-differences-between-rdesktop-and-xfreerdp.

Comment: /v: corresponds to Computer on Pic1. Pic2 is about RD Gateway which is another story, you hardly need it unless you know you do

Comment: Could you provide a command I can use that takes into account the "Computer:", "User name:" and "Server name:" fields shown the pictures? @Tagwint

Comment: Here it is `xfreerdp +clipboard /size:1920x1145 /u:'john.doe@fun.com' /p:'SuperSecurePwd!' /v:rdp.fun.com  -grab-keyboard`  No need of specifiyn Server name in my case. Are you sure you need it in yours?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you use a remote desktop gateway but as of writing I think there may be a problem with sslv3 support in the version I used which is `FreeRDP version 1.1.0-beta1 (git n/a)`

```
xfreerdp /g:<RD gateway ip or hostname> /gu:<RDGatewayUser> /gd:<RDGatewayDomain> /gp:<RDGatewayPassword> /v:<computer>
connected to 10.11.12.13:443
connected to 10.11.12.13:443
SSL_connect: Failure in SSL library (protocol error?)
SSL_connect: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure
```